# How to resolve eclipse errors for java 11 project

Tags: eclipse, java-11

I have migrated to java11 from 8. When I have imported project to eclipse, I see more than 1300 errors. Please check screenshot. [image: Eclipse errors]

Error types are Language servers, Annotations problems, Java problems etc

[image: Eclipse error]

I have made necessary configuration changes to eclipse e.g. setting java11 pref, default jre. Project is maven and i can see it has linked all maven dependencies.
I am not sure why it is still coming.

Eclipse is eclipse-jee-2023-09-R-win32-x86_64

Please comment if you faced this problem.

Comment: Why is there a `system.scope.dir` property, what its meaning and purpose and where is it defined? Why do you have `<systemPath>` which means those dependencies are locally, not from Maven Central. The dependencies looks strange. For example, you have `commons-javaflow:commons-javaflow` of version `001-20060411` locally (`<systemPath>`), but Maven Central provides version [`20060411`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-javaflow/commons-javaflow/20060411), not `001-20060411`. It looks like a hack to use your local modified version of a dependency which is more than 17 years behind.

Comment: To sum it up, `<systemPath>` cannot be resolved as they are specified using the custom  property `system.scope.dir`. But your root problem seems that you use your own modified dependencies locally rather than from Maven Central.

Comment: @howlger I can't change those to use latest. Those are customized libs for project.

Comment: added one more screenshot related to compilation errors.

Comment: You should not have customized libs at all. If a change is required, you have to contribute it. Customized libs cause very high maintenance costs and put safety at risk.

Comment: @howlger I agree. I recently joined the project. It is 17+ years old project with so many weird things.

Comment: Of course, you will get many compile errors if dependencies cannot be resolved. And these dependencies cannot be resolved because `<systemPath>` is used and contains for unknown reasons the unknown/custom property `${system.scope.dir}`. What is the reason to use a custom property here. Do you have different sets of customized libs? Consider to fix the mistakes made by others rather than continue them.

Comment: Where is system.scope.dir set?

Comment: @nitind it is in Pom's properties tag, <system.scope.dir>${basedir}/src/main/lib</system.scope.dir>

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I was able to resolve the errors :)

Root cause for most of compilation errors was package accessibility. Java 11 don't allow if it is accessible from more than one module. One of Error messages was 'The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module'

After removing redundant dependencies from POM file i was able to resolve most of errors. Out of 1300 errors only 8 are left and those are related to POM file as shown in first screenshot of my question. I hope I will find some solution soon.

Thanks :)